# How to find same value(duplicate) in an int array in order?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, int

This is a basic slot game
I am coding in swift, I have an int array of 7 numbers.

The int array can have 1 to 7 values, and they are placed randomly.

```
   1> [1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7]
   2> [3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3]
   3> [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]
   4> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Those are examples of what the array can have.

> In the 1st array you can see that there are 4 pairs of 7s.
>
> In the 3rd array the first 3 are another 3 pair 5s

How do I go about doing this, this is what I have.

```
func processWin(val : Array<Int>){

        var counter = 0;
        var oldValue = 0;

        for num in val {
            if num == oldValue {
                counter++;
            }

            oldValue = num;        
        }

        if counter == 3 {
            print("Three in a row!!!")
        }

        if counter == 4 {
            print("Four in a row!!!")
        }

        if counter == 5 {
            print("Five in a row!!!")
        }
        if counter == 6 {
            print("Six in a row!!!")
        }
        if counter == 7 {
            print("BOOM!")
        }
        print(counter)
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If the array is [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] **Print** `BOOM`

If the array is [1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7] **Print** `Four in a Row`

If the array is [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5] **Print** `Three in a Row`

If the array is [3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5] **Print** `Three in a Row` & `Three in a Row`

If the array is [7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5] **Print** `Four in a Row` & `Three in a Row`

Comment: What is this? Is this the code? It's not [tag:c].

Comment: well, the language doesnt matter. I just want to know the logic

Comment: I don't see 4 pairs of sevens in your first example, and I don't see three pairs of 5s in the third. Do you mean adjacent like numbers? If so, the check in a loop is rather trivial.

Comment: Note that `++` operator [will be removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md), so you're better off using `counter = counter + 1` rather than `counter++`.

Comment: use counter += 1 to be even more concise @dfri

Comment: @shank What do you expect from the 2nd array?

Comment: @zaph it should not do anything ([3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3])

Comment: Update the question with exactly what should happen in all instances.

Comment: @zaph Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a good idea to split up the logic in your code a little. For instance, converting a number to its equivalent word in English is well suited to an extension:

```
extension Int {
  var english: String {
    switch self {
    case 0: return "Zero"
    case 1: return "One"
    case 2: return "Two"
    case 3: return "Three"
    case 4: return "Four"
    case 5: return "Five"
    case 6: return "Six"
    case 7: return "Seven"
    case 8: return "Eight"
    case 9: return "Nine"
    default: return description
    }
  }
}
```

And grouping similar elements in a sequence is something that could also be defined on its own:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Equatable {
  func group() -> [(Generator.Element, Int)] {
    var res: [(Generator.Element, Int)] = []
    for el in self {
      if res.last?.0 == el {
        res[res.endIndex-1].1 += 1
      } else {
        res.append((el,1))
      }
    }
    return res
  }
}
```

And then your function is little shorter and more readable:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Equatable {
  func processWin() -> String {
    return self
      .group()
      .lazy
      .filter { (_,c) in c > 1 }
      .map { (e,c) in c >= 7 ? "Boom!" : c.english + " \(e)s" }
      .joinWithSeparator(", and ")
  }
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7].processWin() // "Four 7s"
[3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3].processWin() // "Two 3s, and Two 3s"
[5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5].processWin() // "Three 5s" 
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].processWin() // "Boom!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to count the number of occurrences in your input array, and then I would switch on the counts.

```
let a = [1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7]
let b = [3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3]
let c = [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]
let d = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

func processWin(val: [Int]) {
    var counts: [Int : Int] = [1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0]

    for item in val {
        counts[item] = counts[item]! + 1
    }

    for (key, value) in counts where value > 1{
        switch value {
            case 2:
                print("A pair of \(key)s")
            case 3:
                print("Three \(key)s")
            case 4:
                print("Four \(key)s")
            case 5:
                print("Five \(key)s")
            case 6:
                print("Six \(key)s")
            case 7:
                print("Seven \(key)s")
            default:
                print("No duplicates")
        }
    }
}

print("A")
processWin(a)
print("B")
processWin(b)
print("C")
processWin(c)
print("D")
processWin(d)
```

This produces the following output:

```
A
Four 7s
B
A pair of 5s
Four 3s
C
Five 5s
D
Seven 2s
```

Comment: Note that it seems (somewhat unclear, though) that the OP only wants to count numbers that are in succession of each other, e.g. his third array gives _"three (fives) in a row"_ and not _"Five 5:s!"_. Compare with your case C above.

Comment: @shank Note that this solution will yield `"Five 5s"` for your third array (`3> [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]`), contrary to what you specified (`"Three in a row!!!"`).

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed about your current code:

1. You will always be one shy of the actual number in a row because you're starting your `counter` at `0` when by definition every number is at least "one in a row"
2. In the event of an array such as `[1,1,1,2,3,3,3]`, you would get an incorrect value of `4` when really the max numbers in a row is `3`.

To fix the first issue, start your `counter` at `1`, and to fix the second, keep track of a `maxInARow` variable, and reset the `counter` whenever `num != oldValue`.

```
func processWin(val: Array<Int>) { 
    var counter = 1 
    var oldValue = 0
    var maxInARow = 0 

    for num in val { 
        if num == oldValue { 
            counter++
            if counter > maxInARow {
                maxInARow = counter 
            } 
        } else {
            counter = 1 
        } 
        oldValue = num 
    } 

    print(maxInARow)
}
```

Comment: it didnt work, if the array is [2,1,1,2,2,2,2], it is printing ``Three in a row!!!\n  Four in a row\n``

Answer (score 0):

I ran this 7 times and tried different arrays. I edited your code slightly, and this runs just fine. I get the same answer every time. Try this and see if you get the same problem. I recommend using a switch statement instead of all of those `if` statements as well.

```
var val:[Int] = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

func processWin(val : Array<Int>){
var counter = 1
var oldValue = 0
for num in val {

    if num == oldValue {
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
    }

    oldValue = num
}

switch counter {
case 3:
    print("Three in a row!!!")
case 4:
     print("Four in a row!!!")
case 5:
    print("Five in a row!!!")
case 6:
    print("Six in a row!!!")
case 7:
    print("BOOM!")
default:
    print("Sorry")
}

print(counter)
}

processWin(val)
//prints BOOM!
```

Also, your counter needs to start at 1. I'm not entirely sure what was happening with your code, but mine seems to work fine.