# Easy way to check an array for contiguous three or more numbers in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift2

Is there any easy way to check if an array contains contiguous value of three or more? 
e.g. `[4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4]` contains two contiguous sequence of 1 and 4.
 To check I wish to give 1 and minimum allowed conjugation, in this case 2, it will just return `true`.
 Thanks.

Comment: edited. thanks for the correction, @Eric D.

Answer (score 1):

We can start out by making use of a neat extension to `SequenceType` by user @oisdk in his answer in the following thread:

- [How to find same value(duplicate) in an int array in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325141/4573247)

The extension groups successive elements in tuples `(value, numberOfSuccessions)`:

```
/* from SO user @oisdk:s answer in Q&A:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325141/4573247 */
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Equatable {
    func group() -> [(Generator.Element, Int)] {
        var res: [(Generator.Element, Int)] = []
        for el in self {
            if res.last?.0 == el {
                res[res.endIndex-1].1 += 1
            } else {
                res.append((el,1))
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Using this, we can swiftly write another extension for checking if---for a given array---a contiguous sequence (for some minimum number of successions/repeats) exists for a given number:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Int {
    func containsContiguousValue(value: Int, forMinimumRepeats rep: Int) -> Bool {
        return !self
            .group()
            .contains{ (val, count) in count >= rep && val == value }
    }
}
```

Used as follows

```
/* Example usage */
let array = [4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4]

array.containsContiguousValue(1, forMinimumRepeats: 3) // true
array.containsContiguousValue(1, forMinimumRepeats: 4) // false
array.containsContiguousValue(4, forMinimumRepeats: 4) // true
array.containsContiguousValue(2, forMinimumRepeats: 3) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest possible way is with the help of the reduce function. If you want you can extend the data structures, but I am not quite a fan of that. So here is a simple solution to your example

```
    // example array
    let a = [4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4]

    let minRepeats = 3      // desired min repeats
    let elementToCheck = 4  // element to check

    let m = a.reduce(0) { (initial: Int, el: Int) -> Int in
        if initial >= minRepeats {
            return initial
        } else {
            return el == elementToCheck ? initial + 1 : 0
        }
    }

    // if m == minRepeats the check is positive, if m < minRepeats the check is negative
    // let check = a.reduce(0){...} == minRepeats gives you the right result
    // Thanks to user3441734 for the correction
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were helpful but not quite as generic as I needed. Also, they are a little outdated, so for those who come across this requirement, here's a generic reusable Swift 4.2 implementation:

An extension on any `Collection` that returns an array of ranges representing the indices of consecutive elements in a collection matching a given predicate.

https://gist.github.com/shaps80/8ec24f82ad1e54d42709277ec2af93a3